# How to create blocked animation with Tween.js?

Tags: javascript, createjs, tween.js

I have this `moveStep()` function to make the Sprite move a step with Tween.js,

```
createjs.Tween.get(this.lion).to({x: x, y: y}, 300);
```

but if `moveStep()` is called more than once, the result is the same as when called once (x, y are calculated in the function).

What is the practical way to chain the animations or block the next animation before this one ended?

I could think of this method:

Calculate the parameters in the function and create a string, then `eval` the chained string at the end. But this seems not so good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `get` an object for a Tween, it is a shortcut for `new createjs.Tween()`, so you are just making a new tween instance, which will run immediately.

To chain tweens, you need to call additional `to` calls on the same Tween instance. If you created a Tween up front, and passed it into the method, that would do what you are asking:

```
function moveStep(tween, x, y) {
    tween.to({x: x, y: y}, 300);  
}

var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.lion);
moveStep(tween, 100,100);
moveStep(tween, 300, 300);
```

You can also construct the `to()` calls in order.

```
var tween = createjs.Tween.get(this.lion)
    .to({x:100,y:100})
    .to({x:300, y:300});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, the first method is the one I need, except I need another pair of properties to store the destination.